# How do I get GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 behavior when GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, startup

I have a question about the grub2 implantation in Ubuntu 12.04.

I have a dual boot system with windows 7, Ubuntu as the primary OS.  When I have `#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` in my `/etc/default` file, grub boots to Ubuntu without showing a menu, and shows the menu when I hold down shift, however, the menu does NOT have my Windows 7 boot drive as an option.

If I have `#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`, Windows 7 shows up in the grub menu, but the grub menu is always shown on system start, even though `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and shift is not held.

Is there a way to have the OS prober turned on, but only have the grub menu shown when shift is held down?

Comment: I was thinking about manually adding the Windows 7 entry, and leaving the OS Prober turned off.  Assuming this gets me the right behavior and a Windows 7 Entry it would be fine for all intents and purposes, but it WOULD be nice to leave the prober turned on.

Comment: ''sudo update-grub''

Answer (score 0):

Only the following two lines should be relevant:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

The first defines the timeout to press the Shift key. Set it to something other then zero, for example 3.

The second tells Grub not to show the menu by default.

Both lines should be uncommented.

Dont forget to run `sudo update-grub` at the end.