# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT and GRUB_TIMEOUT Do Not Accept 0 Value

Tags: boot, grub2, menu

I am not on a duel boot system, and do not want to view the GRUB boot menu. I have used methods that have worked in the past to change /etc/default/grub to accomplish that ends, but they have not worked. I have also followed guides, and they haven't worked either.

/etc/default/grub looks like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Update-grub returns no error messages, and does update /boot/grub/grub.cfg successfully. Indeed, editing this file works for any values for GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT and GRUB_TIMEOUT that are integers and not 0. The problem is I want 0 values however.

How can I get this file to accept 0 values? This same method of editing has worked on this computer for previous installs. I don't know what could be causing it to fail now.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, look at this post here: http://askubuntu.com/a/203940/181527

Comment: try to change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`

Answer (score 1):

This solution combines the best of two related answers.
Please visit the two links below for full explanation:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/742308/757761
- https://askubuntu.com/a/318066/757761

Edit `/etc/default/grub` file with the following settings:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0  
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden    
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.0  
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Then remember to run `sudo update-grub` in your terminal.

I tested this on a pc with multiple operating systems with 100% success.
I am unable to test this on a pc with one operating system, but it should work just the same.