# Edited timeout in /etc/default/grub, and ran update-grub, but timeout remains 10sec

Tags: grub2, timeout

Xubuntu 16.04, Grub 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3

I edited the timeout to 3 seconds:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Timeout during grub boot is still 10 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Suggested duplicate question's answer does not address the specific issue that GRUB_TIMEOUT and GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT cannot both be enabled simultaneously, and therefore to change GRUB TIMEOUT from its default setting, GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT must be commented out.

Comment: Do you have a `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT `  line specified somewhere?

Comment: @Jos, yes: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`

Comment: Comment out these two lines and run `update-grub` again. It should work now. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/475993/grub-update-warning-in-ubuntu-14-04.